# How to change the URL without using <Link> component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In react, one can use the `<Link>` component to change the URL when the user clicks on the `<Link>`.

However, this is not what I want.

I need to change the URL when a `useState` value changes. So I need to change the URL inside of a `useEffect`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use dynamic URL use can use below approach

```
const [link, setLink] = useState('/profile');

useEffect(() => {
 // logic
 setLink('/logout');
}, [state you want]);

return (
 <div>
  <Link to={link} />
 </div>
);
```

or you want to go to a URL after some logic

```
const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
 // logic
 history.push('/profile');
}, [some state])
```

To use useHistory you want import like import *{ useHistory } from "react-router-dom";*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useHistory hook provided with react-router-dom.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```